# Adding a column that is a function of a subset of rows in another column

Tags: r

I know how to add a column that is, say, the sum of two other columns, but I'm looking for a way to make a new column that equals the sum of a subset of rows in another column.

For example, I have a table, "table.1" and the third column "table.1[3]" consists of numbers. I want to add a fourth column such that the 1st row of column 4 = the sum of the values in column 3 from row 1 to 100; the 2nd row = sum of column 3 from row 2 to 101, and so on.

Essentially, at row x, I want table.1[x, 4]=sum(table.1[x:x+99, 3])

Anyone know how I can add a column like that? Thanks.

Comment: Show us the tables (and by tables,I assume you mean data.frames)! Preferably in the form of [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Say the 'table' has 200 rows. What should happen at say row 102? Now x:x+99 is 102:201 - but there is no row 201.

Comment: well, you could either stop or go on like `x:ifelse(x+99 > nrow(table.1), nrow(table.1), x+99)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use the embed() command. In this example your "column 3" is named "a" in the data.frame and i'm adding a column named "b" made up such that dd$b[x]<-sum(dd$a[x:(x+4-1)]) so i'm just using a distance of N=4 rather than N=100 for simplicity.

```
dd<-data.frame(a=c(1,3,6,4,2,4,6,7,8,1))
N<-4
dd$b<-rowSums(embed(c(dd$a, rep.int(0,N-1)), N))
```

Note that I padded the end of the dd$a vector so that when the range "goes off the end", I assume those values to be 0.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly, just what I needed. Would up vote but don't have enough reputation apparently.